# Debug where in render react-native IOS is crashing

Tags: iphone, xcode, react-native

When I call this.setState, the render() function is called.

If there is a problem in the render function, this.seState never completes. How can I figure out where in render() the error is?

I do a

```
console.log('before set state');
this.setState({isLoaded:true});
console.log('after set state');
```

and I see the first console mention be printed, but not the last one. However, in the iOS simulator there are no warnings or errors or anything. I can find the error by deleting one line at a time from render() and seeing when it stops crashing - but there must be a better way to debug this.

Any ideas?

Comment: `setState` should work asynchronously, i.e. it does not call `render()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

setState itself calls for a render

from docs (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) :

> setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional
>   rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate()